# apt policy preferences with multiple orgins

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Is there a way to combine two origins in an apt preferences file ?

With this content

```
Package: dotnet* aspnet* netstandard*
Pin: origin "mirrors.ircam.fr"
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: dotnet* aspnet* netstandard*
Pin: origin "security.ubuntu.com"
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Running this this command I have this output and the priority is respected

```
➜ apt policy dotnet-sdk-7.0
dotnet-sdk-7.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.400-1
  Version table:
     7.0.110-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 -10
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
```

If I try to write the file like this

```
Package: dotnet* aspnet* netstandard*
Pin: origin "mirrors.ircam.fr", origin "security.ubuntu.com"
Pin-Priority: -10
```

I have this result and the priority is not respected anymore

```
apt policy dotnet-sdk-7.0
dotnet-sdk-7.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.400-1
  Version table:

     7.0.110-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 500
        500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
```

Is there a way to ignore everything but microsoft repo for this packages without writing two blocks for each origin ?

Answer (score 1):

In `apt` preferences, [the comma acts like an “and” operator](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt_preferences.5#The_Effect_of_APT_Preferences); since a single repository can’t satisfy two origins, your combined clause can’t be satisfied.

It might be possible to use a disjunction in a regex, but I haven’t tried that in an `origin` clause:

```
Pin: origin /mirrors.ircam.fr|security.ubuntu.com/
```

I suspect it won’t work, and you’ll end up needing to use the two separate stanzas.

Comment: I suspected the comma was doing it, thanks for your confirmation !

I ended up with a simpler solution : `Pin: release o=Ubuntu`

Comment: Ah yes, of course, since the two are Ubuntu repositories!